# Is it possible to programmatically load an SQL dump file using RMySQL?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm storing a database structure in the form of a .sql dump file in my package's configuration folder (stored in `inst/config`). 
At the moment I'm using a command line which requires password input:

```
cat 'filename.sql' | mysql -p databasename
```

In fact I'm suggesting to the user how to load the dump with this function:

```
loaddbstructure <- function(sqlfile = system.file("config/dump.sql",
                                                package="mypackagename", mustWork = TRUE)){
    message("This message gives 2 options to load the database structure.\n\n",
            "(1) If a user called 'R' is created in MySQL, you can run this from a shell command line: \n",
            sprintf("$ cat '%s' | mysql -u R -p tradeflows", sqlfile),
            "\n\n",
            "(2) Another option is to call this from a mysql client:\n",
            "mysql> connect tradeflows;\n",
            sprintf("mysql> source %s;", sqlfile))
}
```

Is it possible to programmatically load this .sql file with a command from RMySQL, using a database connection created with the credentials provided in `~/.my.cnf`?

Comment: Is LOAD DATA INFILE using an established MySQL connection an option?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: @Riedsio it seems LOAD DATA INFILE can not load .sql files, but only data files such as `.csv`. I want to load a sql dump that creates the table structure, with field types and indexes. I would be happy to be wrong.

Comment: How about using the source command?  i.e. from the mysql prompt, run 'source filename.sql'

Comment: @Riedsio I had the password set in a specific group in the [mysql option file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) `~/.my.cnf`, but what I needed was to set `[client] password="my password"` to send the password to any mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

Add connection credentials to the [mysql option file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) located in `~/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
user = R 
password = password
```

Then you can load the database dump with an R command that calls a system bash command (Linux specific):

```
system("cat 'dump.sql' | mysql  databasename")
```